# React Component Recursion inside Route component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

```
class AppRoutes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />

            <Route exact path="/actions" 
            component={() => <Actions mode={0}/>}/>

          <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    );
  }
}
```

The constructor of the `Actions` component is called recursively.

I have also tried

```
            <Route exact path="/actions">
              <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
                <Actions mode={0}/>
              </Suspense>
            </Route>
```

But this just results in the same behaviour. I wish for the `Actions` component to only be called once rather than repetitively, and to allow props to be passed. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there except one.

Please use the following code for router "/actions".

```
class AppRoutes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
          <Route exact path="/actions"
                 render={routeProps => (
                   <Actions {...routeProps} mode={0} />
                 )}
          />
          <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When needing to pass additional props to routed components you'll need to the the [`render`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func) prop instead of the [`component`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/component) prop for the following reason:

> When you use `component` (instead of `render` or `children`, below)
> the router uses [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to create a new [React
> element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) from the given component. That means if you provide an
> inline function to the component prop, you would create a new
> component every render. ***This results in the existing component
> unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the
> existing component.***

What you are calling "The constructor of the Actions component is called recursively." is actually the `Actions` component being remounted repeatedly.

Use the `render` prop instead.

> This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the
> undesired remounting explained above.
>
> Instead of having a new [React element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html) created for you using the
> component prop, you can pass in a function to be called when the
> location matches. The render prop function has access to all the same
> [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (match, location and history) as the component render
> prop.

```
class AppRoutes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner/>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/actions"
            render={(props) => <Actions mode={0} {...props} />}
          />
          <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that the routes have also be ordered in decreasing order of path specificity so the more specific paths can be matched prior to the less specific paths. This eliminates the need to use the `exact` prop. This isn't an issue in `react-router-dom@6` since it uses path rankings instead. Just an FYI when/if you update to the current version.

Comment: This is still causing the recursion issue for me.

Comment: @Corona What recursion are you referring to? I don't see any recursive code in your shared snippet. Can you add all the relevant [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) into your question? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we can inspect and debug live?